# convert a memory location to string in Ghidra

Tags: ida, ghidra

I asked exactly the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77429840/convert-a-memory-location-to-string-in-ghidra), but later I figure out this community and found out this helpful to ask it here as well.

I would like to have a decompiled pseudo-code in `Ghidra` like:

```
FUN_4c4363e8("Hello world");
```

This is what usually I see in `IDA` , but in Ghidra, by default I get such a code:

```
FUN_4c4363e8((char*)(DAT_4c447798));
```

Is there a way to force the decompiler to convert the `DAT_4c447798` memory address to `"Hello world"` null-terminated string?

Thanks.

Comment: right click on the location > Data > Choose TerminatedCString

Comment: @sudhackar Did not help. It still stays the same LABEL pointer and not a string in decompiled C pseudocode.

Comment: Can you share the bytes that's supposed to be the string? possible to share binary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this DAT_4c447798 is a pointer and it should point to the string.

Ghidra acts much better, if you specify that some memory areas are constant.
In the menu check `Window` -> `Memory map` and remove ticks at `W` column for all areas where your code does not wrote to.

And of course, please provide more details in further questions.

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks. I had a lot limitations to tell more than what I said in my question.